# Comparing two columns in two different excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

- I have 2 excel sheets (sheet1 and sheet2)
- Sheet1 has 10 columns, sheet2 has 20 columns (no:of rows are same )
- Sheet2 contains all the columns that sheet1 have
- Now, compare 12th column of sheet2 with 7th column of sheet1
- This should result in another column names 'Matched?' in any of the sheet (lets say sheet 2)
- This 'Matched?' columns should have 500 rows with values 'Yes' if matched (or) 'No' if not matched.

**Note:** Kindly please start explaining from the scratch about the provided VLOOKUP() function because i don't know about it.

Comment: Do you  care if you have duplicates in the 7th or in the 12th column?

Comment: No,it doesn't have duplicates

Comment: VLOOKUP is very good if you have a table and will search for a value, when you find the value, you want tor return a value from the column to the right of your lookup value. For comparing I think there are more efficient ways to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little formula will do the trick for you:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!G:G; L2)=0, "No match in Sheet1", "Match in Sheet1")
```

Where "Sheet1" is the name of the worksheet 1

You could then modify it to (the above formula is to clearly show the logic):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!G:G; L2)=0, "No", "Yes")
```

Assume we have Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2, we apply our formula in the column V. It check if the word Apple (cell `L2` exist anywhere in Sheet 1, column G). We do this for every row.

[image]

For next row we want to check if it exist in Sheet1, we apply the formula again, the only difference is that `L2` -> `L3` i.e. the reference value changes since you are looking at another row.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But can you please explain whether I should apply this look up formula for all the 500 rows? if not then in which particular cell do I need to add this?

Comment: Np :), for all the 500 rows. // In my example, the formula checks for one value in Sheet2 (Apple) and then then compare it to the whole column of Sheet1 (Looks if Apple exist at all in column G). It do this for every row indivdually, therefore the formula needs to be for every row you want to check. // Apply it in the first row you want to see if it match, and then just drag the formula down (as you can see in my second picture).

Comment: Yeah, that went fine. Thank you, please don't mind if I continue adding comment to seek your help regarding this.

Comment: No problem :), Feel free to ask and welcome to SO. It might suit to start a new question if the topic deviates to much :)!! Take care!